# How to Execute Liquibase script in Jenkins without installing liquibase plugins as shell scripts

Tags: jenkins, sh, powershell-3.0, liquibase, jenkins-groovy

We are using Liquibase 3.6.3 version

We are running SQL upgrade scripts using liquibase on the SQL Server Database using liquibase.bat(which we got as part of installation) as below on our local windows machines. This is working as expected.

**Command:**

liquibase.bat --changeLogFile=..\MasterChangelog.xml --driver==com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver --classpath=sqljdbc4-3.0.jar 
--url="jdbc:sqlserver://;databaseName=MyDB;user=MyUser;password=MyPassword;" --logLevel=INFO update

Now our requirement is to achieve the same through Jenkins as we are currently moving towards AWS.

**Questions:**

•   Do we have any supported liquibase plugins for Jenkins ?

•   Do we have any bash supported scripts something which will behave same as liquibase.bat

•   Do we have any shell command snippets to execute liquibase scripts on Jenkins?

•   Any script snippets so that we can use them in Jenkins pipeline

Is there any other way of achieving this?

Comment: are you using liquibase inside some java project? If so, liquibase has maven plugin which can be used for that.

Comment: Hello Bilak, my aim is to run the Liquibase scripts on Jenkins pipeline as bash script instead of using liquibase.bat file and also i am not allowed to use the Jenkins-Liquibase plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `liquibase` shell script that ships with liquibase that is equivalent to `liquibase.bat`.

There is at least one Jenkins plugin for Liquibase - https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Liquibase+Runner

Comment: Thanks Steve. Seems to be the Jenkins plugin  Distribution  has been suspended due to unresolved security vulnerabilities. That's the reason our team is not encouraging to install the plugin. Could you please help me to share the command snippet / reference so that I can give a try on this and see how it works.

Comment: If your `liquibase.bat` command works on Windows, the equivalent `liquibase` command will work on Linux. If that is not the case, ask again with full details: what was the command you used, the environment, etc. What were the results of that? How did those results differ from your expectations?

Comment: Thanks Steve. Not sure if i am missing anything when I ran the command last time. Let me verify your suggestion again and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks Steve. Not sure what might went wrong initially when i tried, but now it is working as expected. Thanks for suggestions and time on this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be this is working for me.

**Windows:**

liquibase.bat --changeLogFile=..\MasterChangelog.xml --driver==com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver --classpath=sqljdbc4-3.0.jar --url="jdbc:sqlserver://;databaseName=MyDB;user=MyUser;password=MyPassword;" --logLevel=INFO update

**bash script:**

./liquibase --changeLogFile=../MasterChangeLog.xml '--url=jdbc:sqlserver://MyDB;databaseName=MyDB;user=MyUser;password=MyPassword;' --logLevel=INFO update

Comment: for the benefit of all, some difference comparing windows and unix, unix is case sensitive and the slashes we use should be very careful, forward and backward slashes and need to use chmod +x command against the file on which we will like to execute to provide execution privileges in UNIX.